# why my react useLayoutEffect hook render twice in chorme debugger mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to my understanding, when i hit the div element on the page, value will be set to 0,then useLayoutEffect hook trigger,value will be set to a random value, all this process will block ui thread from render, then this random value will be rendered to the page. but actually in debugger mode, after click event triggered, i set a breakpoint in useLayoutEffect hook, value 0 actually was rendered in the page, i am very confused about this, shouldn't be js thread block ui thread from rendering here ?
Here is the code

```
const OnlyTest = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  const mountedRef = useRef(false)
  // useEffect(() => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!mountedRef.current) {
      console.log("first mount")
      mountedRef.current = true
    }
    console.log("useEffect_callback_trigger")
    if (value === 0) {
      setValue(10 + (+Math.random().toFixed(2)))
    }
  }, [value])
  return (<div onClick={() => {
    console.log("onClick_trigger")
    setValue(0)
  }} style={{
    width: "100px",
    background: "green",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white",
    padding: "4px",
    cursor: "pointer"
  }}>value:{value}</div>)
}
```

the code above works just fine,it prevent the value  from blinking,but in debug mode,it still blinks,why?